# no data is added to list of integer in android

Tags: android, list, gson, indexoutofboundsexception

I have json data from webservice that should be stored in two lists, String list and Integer List. the one for strings stores the data fine but the one for the integers doesn't. it prompts error saying  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

here is the complete code

```
 public class Setup extends AppCompatActivity {
Button save;
EditText schoolPK;
String schoolname, classname, cityname, school_id,class_id;
ImageView logout;
GridView grid;
String cityid,classid;
int schoolid;
ArrayList<String> CityName, CityId;
private List<Integer> classID=new ArrayList<Integer>();
private List<String> listschools = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> listclasses = new ArrayList<String>();

Spinner schoolspinner;
public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
public static final String classnames = "classname";
public static final String schoolnames = "schoolname";
public static final String Email = "emailKey";
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

String saved_letter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setup2);



    CityName=new ArrayList<>();
    CityId = new ArrayList<>();
    //classID = new ArrayList<>();
   // schoolID = new ArrayList<>();

    schoolPK = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.schoolPK);


    final Spinner city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city);
   final Spinner classspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.classname);
    String URL_countries="http://192.168.0.148/Election/api/school";
    JsonArrayRequest items = new JsonArrayRequest(URL_countries, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0;i<response.length();i++){
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String country=obj.getString("name_Ar");
                    String cityid = obj.getString("pK_ID");
                    CityId.add(cityid);
                    CityName.add(country);
                }


                catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                city.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Setup.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, CityName));
            }
            //to get me the



        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            AlertDialog.Builder add = new AlertDialog.Builder(Setup.this);
            add.setMessage(error.getMessage()).setCancelable(true);
            AlertDialog alert = add.create();
            alert.setTitle("error");
            alert.show();
        }
    } );


    Controller.getInstance(Setup.this).addToRequestque(items);
    city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            cityname = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            cityid = CityId.get(position).toString();
            //CityId.clear();
            listclasses.clear();
            getclasses();

        } // to close the onItemSelected

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    classspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            classname = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                class_id = classID.get(position).toString();

        }
        // to close the onItemSelected

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Settings", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
            Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Vote.class);

            editor.putString("schoolname", cityname);
            editor.putString("schoolid", cityid);
            editor.putString("classname", classname);
            editor.putString("classid", class_id);


            editor.apply();
        }
    });
}


public void getschools(){

    try {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String URL = "http://192.168.0.148/Election/api/School";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        // jsonBody.put("tblRegisteredUsers_nickName", username.getText().toString().trim());
        jsonBody.put("cityFK_ID", cityid);



        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //my response later should be changed

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString;
                String json = null;
                try {
                    json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                responseString = String.valueOf(json).trim();
                ArrayList<Schoolresponse> list_response = new ArrayList<Schoolresponse>();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Schoolresponse>>() {}.getType();
                list_response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, listType);
               // schoolID= new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < list_response.size(); i++) {
                    School listItemData = new School();
                    listItemData.setName(list_response.get(i).getNameAr());
                    listItemData.setId(list_response.get(i).getPKID());

                    //schoolID.add(listItemData.getId());
                    listschools.add(listItemData.getName());
                }

                // i should have this piece of code for methods that are running in the background
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        schoolspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Setup.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listschools));
                    }
                });


                return Response.success(list_response.toString(), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }





public void getclasses(){

    final  Spinner classspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.classname);
    try {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        String URL = "http://192.168.0.148/Election/api/classes";
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        // jsonBody.put("tblRegisteredUsers_nickName", username.getText().toString().trim());
        jsonBody.put("SchoolFK_ID", cityid);



        final String requestBody = jsonBody.toString();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //my response later should be changed

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("VOLLEY", error.toString());
            }
        })

        {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                try {
                    return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", requestBody, "utf-8");
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString;
                String json = null;
                try {
                    json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                responseString = String.valueOf(json).trim();
                ArrayList<ClassResponse> list_response = new ArrayList<ClassResponse>();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ClassResponse>>() {}.getType();
                list_response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, listType);
                for (int i = 0; i < list_response.size(); i++) {
                    School listItemData = new School();
                    listItemData.setName(list_response.get(i).getNameAr());
                    listItemData.setId(list_response.get(i).getPKID());

                    classID.add(listItemData.getId());
                    listclasses.add(listItemData.getName());
                }

                // i should have this piece of code for methods that are running in the background
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        classspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Setup.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listclasses));
                    }
                });
                // String Check =  yourModel.getMessagetitle();

                return Response.success(list_response.toString(), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here is the area I'm talking about 
where only the string list (listclasses) is storing data while the integer (classID) list does not

```
        protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                String responseString;
                String json = null;
                try {
                    json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                responseString = String.valueOf(json).trim();
                ArrayList<ClassResponse> list_response = new ArrayList<ClassResponse>();
                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ClassResponse>>() {}.getType();
                list_response = new Gson().fromJson(responseString, listType);
                for (int i = 0; i < list_response.size(); i++) {
                    School listItemData = new School();
                    listItemData.setName(list_response.get(i).getNameAr());
                    listItemData.setId(list_response.get(i).getPKID());

                    classID.add(listItemData.getId());
                    listclasses.add(listItemData.getName());
                }

                // i should have this piece of code for methods that are running in the background
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        classspinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Setup.this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, listclasses));
                    }
                });
                // String Check =  yourModel.getMessagetitle();

                return Response.success(list_response.toString(), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            }
        };
```

hope I get right answer
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Ahmed, can you please share the json response. Have you cross verified, if the response is having the integer with correct tag name that you are looking for?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075657/sudhin-philip
    {
        "pK_ID": 5657,
        "name_En": "صف 1 ",
        "name_Ar": "صف 1 ",
        "fkiD_VotingCenter": 10006,
        "letters": "ا",
        "isActive": true,
        "entryDate": null,
        "enteredBy": null,
        "updateDate": null,
        "updatedBy": null
    },

Comment: no problems in the json, im using pojohttps://stackoverflow.com/users/1075657/sudhin-philip

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

means that your Array is empty and you are trying to access array element from an empty array.

You can put a condition to check if array length is more than 0 and then proceed using it like:

```
if(array != null && array.length > 0){
   // do parsing

}
```

Comment: yea i know it is zero, but why it is zero ?

Comment: try to debug and see if you are getting an empty JSON array from your server.

Comment: solved after debugging, thanks for the simple hint looolhttps://stackoverflow.com/users/1439968/ash

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class `School` contains variable with name `pK_ID`. Look carefully on the upper/lower cases in the variable name.

If the variable name is not matching with JSON tag then this will result in empty fetching from JSON, even if you are getting valid JSON from URL as per your comment.